# PHPDom iterate through document and remove nodes without XPath

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I am trying to iterate through a document, and remove nodes (in my case all divs), but without xpath (I Can already do this with xpath). For some reason, only the first div gets removed. Any tips?

```
<?php

//my totally random html        
$html = '<p> Great <div> dont want this</div> </p><p> some more</p><div>more crap here</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);  

iterate_children($doc );
print $doc->saveHTML();


function iterate_children(&$object){
    //print_r($object);

    if ($object->tagName == "div") {
        $object->parentNode->removeChild($object);
        iterate_children($object->parentNode);
    }
    else {
        //if($object->hasChildNodes()) {
        foreach($object->childNodes as $child) {
            //
            iterate_children($child);
        //}
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: why do you make use of a reference here? you don't work on a variable alias here nor are there any changes to the value of the parameter variable?!

Comment: Good call. I had some lame reasoning when I used that reference, but dont recall now. It was getting late and I desperate... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why only the first div gets removed is perhaps most simple explained this way:

You iterate over all child-nodes. This iteration starts by setting the current node to the first child ([`DOMNode::$firstChild`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.firstchild)). Then you process that child and when done you continue to the next child (that is then [`DOMNode::$nextSibling`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nextsibling)).

But if you now remove the current node from the parent

```
$object->parentNode->removeChild($object);
```

The current node in iteration does not have any next-sibling any longer (as it has been removed from it's parent). Therefore the *foreach* iteration ends immediately after you've removed the first *div* element.

There are different ways to approach this problem. With pure PHP and not using any xpath, you can store all nodes to remove in an array first and then remove them. The function [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/iterator_to_array) is quite handy in such situations:

```
$divs = iterator_to_array($doc->getElementsByTagName('div'));
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $div->parentNode->removeChild($div);
}
```

These four lines of code do replace all the iteration and recursion logic of your (not working) function (!).

You could also fix your function by using a [**CachingIterator**](http://php.net/CachingIterator) which has internally already the next element while you iterate the current one (the current element is cached). It won't get invalidated then because the moment you remove the current node from the parent, the next node has been already fetched.

Roughly for your code that would change the following lines:

```
foreach($object->childNodes as $child) {            
    iterate_children($child);
}
```

to:

```
$children = $object->childNodes;
$children = new IteratorIterator($children);
$children = new CachingIterator($children, CachingIterator::TOSTRING_USE_KEY);
foreach ($children as $child) {
    iterate_children($child);
}
```

but take note that this code is for demonstration purposes only. If you would copy & paste that into your example, it would crash because you have some other problems in your code which would become serious with such a change.

This code would still have the recursion that actually is not necessary as you could iterate the nodes in document order. For that I've got a **DOMNodeIterator** in the [*Iterator Garden*](https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden). That library also has a simple **DOMElementFilter** in the [*development* branch](https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden/tree/development). As the problem with the next-sibling is the same here, using those two requires a **CachingITerator** again as well:

```
$divs = new CachingIterator(new DOMElementFilter(new DOMNodeIterator($doc), 'div'), CachingIterator::TOSTRING_USE_KEY);
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $div->parentNode->removeChild($div);
}
```

This code is again pretty similar to the `iterator_to_array` example. As often iterators enable you to create more re-useable code thanks to their decorating nature.

I hope this has helped you to understand why this happened and also showed some ways to deal with this.

---

For completeness reasons, here your code with better error-handling and traversal logic:

```
function iterate_children(DOMNode $node)
{
    if ($node instanceof DOMElement and $node->tagName == "div") {
        $parent = $node->parentNode;
        $parent->removeChild($node);
        return;
    }

    $children = $node->childNodes;
    if (!$children) {
        return;
    }

    $children = new IteratorIterator($children);
    $children = new CachingIterator($children, CachingIterator::TOSTRING_USE_KEY);
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        iterate_children_old($child);
    }
}
```

---

And here the implementation without recursion and with array:

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPDom iterate through document and remove nodes without XPath
 */

/my totally random html
$html = '<p> Great <div> dont want this</div> </p><p> some more</p><div>more crap here</div>';

$doc          = new DOMDocument();
$doc->recover = true;
$saved        = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($saved);

$divs = iterator_to_array($doc->getElementsByTagName('div'));
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $div->parentNode->removeChild($div);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```